# Syntax error while running node.js file

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, syntax-error

Folks I am working on the Editinplace functionality and while running I get this error on the chrome console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` I am doing this with the node.js snippet as follows

```
case '/':
res.writeHead(302,{'location':'http://localhost/editinplace/index.html'});
res.end();
break;
case '/save':
console.log("called");

    console.log("Inside called");
    res.write('_testcb(\'{"message": "Hello world!"}\')');
res.writeHead(302,{'location':'http://localhost/editinplace/save.html'});

res.end();
break;
```

The code for the index.html is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setClickable();
});
function setClickable() {
$('#editInPlace').click(function() {
var textarea = '<div><textarea rows="10" cols="60">'+$(this).html()+'</textarea>';
var button = '<div><input type="button" value="SAVE" class="saveButton" /> OR <input type="button" value="CANCEL"class="cancelButton" /></div></div>';
var revert = $(this).html();
$(this).after(textarea+button).remove();
$('.saveButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, false);});
$('.cancelButton').click(function(){saveChanges(this, revert);});
})
.mouseover(function() {
$(this).addClass("editable");
})
.mouseout(function() {
$(this).removeClass("editable");
});
};//end of function setClickable
function saveChanges(obj, cancel) {
if(!cancel) {
var t = $(obj).parent().siblings(0).val();
var data=t;
 $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9090/save',
        type:"GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "_testcb",
        cache: true,
        timeout: 1000,
        data:{data:JSON.stringify(data)},
        success: function(data) {
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });
}
else {
var t = cancel;
}
$(obj).parent().parent().after('<div id="editInPlace">'+t+'</div>').remove() ;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="editInPlace">Nilesh</div>
</body>
```

The save.html is a simple text enclosed in `<pre>`tags.And the error is shown to be in save.html line 1.Thankx for your efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so here's what happens:

- browser loads index.html
- user edits the field and clicks save
- `saveChanges` makes an AJAX GET request to `/save`
- Your server code sends an HTTP response with a 302 status code and a jsonp body
- I think that the browser is transparently handling the 302 status code and ignoring the body
- Thus your jquery code is expecting your javascript from the response body of `/save`, but it's really getting the HTML from `/save.html`. That's where the syntax error happens, when jquery tries to evaluate that HTML as javascript because you told it the `dataType` was `jsonp`.

See also [this question about browsers handling redirects automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)

The solution is you need to send a 200 response code so jquery can do the jsonp thing and then after that you can change `window.location` to `/save.html` if you like.